# Bordism classes of real projective plane

Tags: geometry, cobordism

I have to prove that doesn't exist a compact $3$-manifold such that $\partial X=  \mathbb{R}P^2$. My book suggests to use Euler characteristic and define $Y = X \cup_{\mathbb{R}P^2} X$. What is $X \cup_{\mathbb{R}P^2} X$ ?  How can I make the proof?

Comment: Hint: Use the fact that every compact 3-manifold without boundary has zero Euler characteristic. Then relate Euler characteristics of X and Y.

Comment: @studiosus But I don't know how $\cup_{\mathbb{R}P^2}$ is defined...

Comment: @ArthurStuart $X\cup_{\mathbb{R}P^2} X$ means glue two copies of $X$ along their boundary $\mathbb{R}P^2$s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is just a hint, not a complete answer:

Suppose you have two manifolds with boundary $M_1, M_2$ and a homeomorphism $h: \partial M_1\to \partial M_2$ of their boundaries. Then one can define a new manifold $M_1\cup_h M_2$ by taking the quotient of the *disjoint union* $M_1\sqcup M_2$, by the equivalence relation $x\sim h(x), x\in \partial M_1$. A special case of this construction is called the *double of a manifold along its boundary*, where $M_1=M_2$, $\partial M_1=N$, and $h$ is the identity map of the boundary to itself. The result of doubling is usually denoted $M_1\cup_N M_1$. (Here is is very important to use the disjoint union in the construction.) The result of the general gluing construction is a manifold $M$ without boundary. A nice exercise now is to compute (in the case of compact manifolds) $\chi(M)$ in terms of $\chi(M_1), \chi(M_2)$ and $\chi(\partial M_1)$ by first assuming that manifolds in question are triangulated. (The same answer works in general, just requires a bit more work.)

Now, in the case of $N=RP^2$, one needs to compute $\chi(RP^2)$ and use the fact that $\chi(M)=0$, as $M$ is a closed odd-dimensional manifold.

Comment: But $\chi(M \cup_{N} M)=2\chi (M)-1$?

Comment: @ArthurStuart: Yes, that's the way to do it.

Comment: But how can I prove it? I deduced this formula making some examples...

Comment: Assume triangulability and just count the simplices.